# Best option for creating user interface with embedded matlab functions

Tags: windows, matlab

I have created a matlab function to do a mathematical calculation. I have made a desktop standalone application using GUIDE, but it takes about a minute to start the application. It is too slow i think for such a simple application.(mathematical calculation with 2 user input variable -> no graphical display)

I just wondering, is it possible to make user interface outside matlab, but keeping my matlab function to do the calculation?

If yes, can you please give me option to start with?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB takes quite a while to start, especially with the GUI enabled. Starting it with `-nojvm` is quite a bit faster, but then you don’t have a GUI (desktop) nor figure windows.

So if you create an external application that calls MATLAB, you can start MATLAB in the background with the `-nojvm` option. There is an API for an external application calling MATLAB and getting data in and out, called [MATLAB Engine API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html) (it exists for other languages too, look around the MATLAB web site).

Yet another option is to use [MATLAB Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) to convert your MATLAB code to stands-alone C or C++ code, which you can then link to your application.